# Download generated excel file

Tags: asp.net, excel

Following code given:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelFile = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
excelFile.Visible = false;
Workbook wb = excelFile.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
Worksheet sheet1 = wb.ActiveSheet as Worksheet;
sheet1.Name = "Test";
sheet1.Cells[1, 1] = "Test";

string fileName = Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) + "\\tickets.xlsx";
wb.SaveAs(Filename: fileName, FileFormat: XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, AccessMode: XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange);
wb.Close();
excelFile.UserControl = true;
excelFile.Quit();
```

This generates an excelfile and saves it to the desktop. What do I have to change to ask for a save location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using excel on the server is not supported and opens a whole can of worms, especially the is a high risk that excel pops up a dialog, which cannot be dismissed because no one sees the server desktop. Also, excel is very slow, generating a critical bottleneck. Last, debugging this is nearly impossible - this solution works, but will never work well.

The solution: use a library like epplus which can read / write xlsx files easily, is faster to develop, magnitudes faster in building the file and free. There are other libraries out there which can read xls files, if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the "EPPlus"-tip. Like you said, fast to develop and solves all my problems!

Answer (score -1):

Prior to setting the filename, you could open the [SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: -1, because the question is for web (not desktop programming), the SaveFileDialog did not work here, second this have nothing to do with the issue, the user all ready give a file name for the save.